# nohup script calling nohup scripts

Tags: command-line, rhel

I'm trying to run a shell script which is running few SQLplus scripts using nohup call . 
This is working fine.

Now each child SQLplus script is taking lot of time to execute (like more than 1hour due to valid reason).
Can I run the parent shell script using nohup also?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. But it would be enough to run the main script through `nohup`.

You may consider `screen` as a superior alternative.